# React-native - Pagination in horizontal FlatList with separators

Tags: react-native

How to adjust horizontal FlatList with separators in order to skip separators when pagination is enabled. I want to see separators only when swiping between items. I tried to set it in getItemLayout but it doesn't work properly. I used `getItemLayout = (_, index) => ({ length: window.width, offset: (window.width + separatorWidth) * index, index })` [Behaviour looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlIyk.gif)

Comment: Please post an example and show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @cguedel I updated my question, there is also .gif of behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

This confused me as well.

There are a few `snap` related properties inherited/extended from `<ScrollView>` that are useful here.
Checkout: [`snapToInterval`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#snaptointerval) and [`snapToOffsets`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#snaptooffsets).

If you're using a `<FlatList>` or `<ScrollView>` to act as a horizontal full-width carousel, and want to enforce snapping so that a single "page" within the list is always within view (i.e. users can't stop partially between views), these snap props are what you need.

*Note*: you need to *disable* [`pagingEnabled`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#pagingenabled) in order for these props to be respected.

**Simplified example code:**

```
render() {
  const totalItemWidth = window.width + separatorWidth;

  return (
    <FlatList
      { /* ... other props — data, renderItem, style, etc ... */}
      horizontal
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      snapToInterval={totalItemWidth}
      decelerationRate="fast"
      bounces={false}
      getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
        length: totalItemWidth,
        offset: totalItemWidth * index,
        index,
      })}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={SomeSeparatorComponent}
    />
  )
}
```

**How it behaves on iOS verse Android:**

[image]
[image]

Android is a bit clunkier and I'm still refining the `decelerationRate` and overall feel... but it's close, IMO.